# Crontab not working, and some more crontab questions

Tags: bash, cron

I've been trying to run a script every minute using crontab but it won't run. The code I put into for it is:

```
* * * * * ~/me/folder/myScript.sh
```

I figured that the destination about is wrong so I also tried:

```
* * * * * home/me/folder/myScript.sh
```

I'm very new with bash so I'm a bit clueless what the problem might be. I've tried `pgrep cron` to make sure I had cron running.

Comment: That is not the problem, I've made sure it's executable

Comment: What happens when you run the command from a shell prompt?

Comment: The script runs as it should do.

Answer (score 0):

The current directory when running your crontab is your home directory, so you don't need to put an explicit path to it.

```
* * * * * folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh >>myScript.log 2>&1
```

But if you want that, you need to make it an absolute path:

```
* * * * * /home/me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh >>/home/me/myScript.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Are there any messages in syslog from `CRON` about it?

Comment: Where can I view that? I don't get any errors after updating my `crontab -e`, it just says it's been updated.

Comment: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: These two messages get displayed every minute:

    Nov 22 18:03:01 user CRON[22352]: (user) CMD      (home/user/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh)
    Nov 22 18:03:01 user CRON[22351]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed,     discarding output)

Comment: So your script is running, but it's getting an error. Normally `cron` will mail the output to you, but since mail isn't configured on your machine it's not able to do that. I'll update my answer to show how you can put the output in a file.

Comment: If the script works when you run it interactively, the error is probably because it depends on some environment variables you set in your `.profile`. This is not executed when running cron jobs.

Comment: `/bin/sh: 1: home/user/folder1/myScript.sh: not found` This is the error message I got in the log. I changed folder to make it a bit easier.

Comment: You're missing the `/` before `home`. Do you understand the difference between absolute and relative pathnames?

Comment: I noticed that as well so I fixed it, but it's still displaying the same problem, both in the syslog and the generated log

Comment: What happens if you type `ls /home/user/folder1/myScript.sh`? Make sure you copy **exactly** what you put in the crontab.

Comment: I get a message in green `/home/user/folder1/myScript.sh` For some reason my log file isn't displaying any error messages anymore though, So I guess one step on the way

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell since you're using anonymized examples, but I think you're using the wrong paths for your script. Generally, paths will be in one of 3 formats:

- Absolute paths: these are distinguished by starting with "/", and the path is specified starting from the root of the system volume. If I'm understanding your example properly, your script is at the absolute path "/home/me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh".
- Home-based paths: these start with "~", optionally followed by a username. Assuming your username is "me" and your home directory is "/home/me", you could specify your script with either "~/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh" or "~me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh".

  The path you used, "~/me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh", is equivalent to "/home/me/me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh". Note the "me/me/" bit -- that's because of the "/" between "~" and "me".

  (BTW, it's not important here, but these are not real paths; they're a shorthand the shell supports, so they can be used only in places where the command is interpreted by a shell or something similar.)
- Relative paths: these don't start with either "/" or "~", and the path is specified relative to the process's current working directory.

  In a cron job, the working directory is (at least initially) set to the user's home folder. Thus, when you specify the path "home/me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh", it's equivalent to the absolute path "/home/me/home/me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh".

So the net result is that you should be able to use any of the following paths:

```
/home/me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh
~/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh
~me/folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh
folder1/folder2/folder3/myScript.sh
```

Comment: I have tried all of those and I still get the same errors in the syslog and the script is still not running every minute.